Optimizating an iterative calculation of a[i] = a[i-1]*b[i] + c[i] with NumPy
I would like to optimize a calculation involving the recursive formula:
#a, b, c are arrays of shape (N, )

a[0] = c[0]

for i in range(1, N):
    a[i] = a[i-1]*b[i] + c[i]

Is there a way to return the result a with a combination of optimized NumPy methods? such as cumprod, cumsum and dot?

consider just using numba

there seems to be no such way

This can be done with the SciPy function scipy.signal.lfilter.  See the duplicate question "Recursive definitions in Pandas".  Don't worry about the reference to Pandas, it is not required to use lfilter.  See also "Can I use numpy to speed this loop?".

There is actually a way to use a combination of np.cumsum and np.cumprod to solve this problem for any fixed n. I will use 1-based indexing to illustrate how this works.
Problem:
Let b be a length n-1 array and c be a length n array, we want a way to streamline the calculation of array a:
a[1] = c[1], a[i+1] = a[i]*b[i] + c[i+1] for all 1 <= i <= n-1

using only vectorized and optimized numpy operations (cumprod & cumsum).
Solution:
We define an array D length n as follows:
D[n] = 1, D[n-1] = 1/(b[n-1]), D[n-2] = 1/(b[n-1]*b[n-2]), ..., D[1] = 1/(b[n-1]*b[n-2]*...*b[1])

Basically D is the cumprod of 1/b[::-1] padded by a 1 in the beginning.
Then, we set d length n in a vectorized method as follows:
d[i] = c[i]/D[i] for all i <= n

and then the cumsum of d[i] we will call S, will be defined as S[i] = d[1]+d[2]+...+d[i].
Before finishing the proof, observe that D[i+k]/D[i] = b[i]*b[i+1]*...*b[i+k-1]
Finally, I claim a[i] = D[i]*S[i] for all i <= n, lets see:
D[1]*S[1] = D[1]*(c[1]/D[1]) = c[1] = a[1]
D[2]*S[2] = D[2](c[1]/D[1] + c[2]/D[2]) = (D[2]/D[1])*c[1] + c[2] = b[1]*c[1]+c[2] = a[2]
D[3]*S[3] = (D[3]/D[1])*c[1] + (D[3]/D[2])*c[2] + c[3] = b[2]*b[1]*c[1] + b[2]*c[2] + c[3]

and the rest follows inductively to see that for D[k]*S[k], the c[i] component is always scaled by D[k]/D[i] = b[i]*...*b[k-1] which is exactly how much c[i] should be scaled in a[k] by its recursive definition.

No, this sort of algorithms are hard to vectorize (using just numpy). I recommend to look at numba. Example:
import numba
import numpy as np


@numba.njit
def compute(a, b, c):
    a[0] = c[0]

    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        a[i] = a[i - 1] * b[i] + c[i]


N = 10
a = np.empty(N, dtype="int64")
b = np.arange(1, N + 1, dtype="int64")
c = np.arange(10, N + 10, dtype="int64")

# note - when run for first time, numba compiles the function (this takes some time).
# Next runs numba uses already compiled function which is fast
compute(a, b, c)
print(a)

Prints:
[      10       31      105      433     2179    13089    91639   733129
  6598179 65981809]

